# Can not find element with requests/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I write a web scraper with requests and BeautifulSoup, and there's an element in the DOM I can't find.

Here's what I do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://www.decitre.fr/rechercher/result/?q=victor+hugo&search-scope=3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

The element I can't find is the "old-price" (the one which is striked-through), which I can see when I inspect the DOM with a browser dev tool.

```
soup.find_all(class_='old-price') # returns [], no matter if I specify "span"
```

Moreover I can't see the 'old-price' string in the soup or the result of the request:

```
'old-price' in soup.text # False
'old-price' in r.text # False
```

I can't see it when I get the source with `wget` too.

I can get its div parent, but can't find price children inside it:

```
commands = soup.find_all(class_='product_commande')
commands[0].find_all('old-price') # []
```

So I have no idea what's going on. What am I missing ?

- do I badly use request/BeautifulSoup ? (I'm not sure if r.text returns the full html)
- is that html part generated with a javascript code ? if so how can I know it and is there a way to get the complete html ?

many thanks

Comment: Possibly `old-price` element is being generated after executing some `javascript` code.

Comment: It´s a dynamicly loaded JavaScript element, so maybe try python Ghost[http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/] to load the website and then parse it´s content via BeautifulSoup (or Ghost via a JS-Query)

Comment: Looks like Ghost is the way to go, thanks. «Executing javascripts inside webkit frame is one of the most interesting features provided by Ghost». Will try as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was passing invalid HTML into Beautiful Soup which was causing it to ignore everything after the invalid tag at the start of the document:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?-->
```

Note that I am also using `Ghost.py`. Here is how I removed the tag.

```
#remove invalid xml tag
ghostContent = ghost.content
invalidCode = '<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?-->'
if ghostContent.startswith(invalidCode):
    ghostContent = ghostContent[len(invalidCode):]

doc = BeautifulSoup(ghostContent)     

#test to see if we can find text   
if 'Application Search Results' in doc.text:
    print 'YES!'
```